# How to Magento's default template for the product description page?

Tags: php, magento-1.7

How can I change Magento's default template for product detailed/ single/ description page?

By default, it is always pulling this template,

```
 frontend\MY_WEBSITENAME\default\template\page/2columns-right.phtml
```

What about if I want it to pull this layout instead?

```
2columns-left.phtml
```

so the path should be,

```
frontend\MY_WEBSITENAME\default\template\page/2columns-left.phtml
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add to or edit `catalog.xml` in your theme.

File located at (if you do not have it, copy it from the `base` theme):

```
/app/design/frontend/MY_WEBSITENAME/default/layout/catalog.xml
```

Change:

```xml
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

to:

```xml
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

In Magento 1.7's `catalog.xml` file it should be on line `179` (I believe).